# Updating a Choice Field in SharePoint Designer 2013 Workflow

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, designer-workflow, choice-field

Is it possible to update information from one choice field into another choice field in a different list? Or do you need to copy it to a text field?

Here's the Update List Item action when I try to setup:

[image: Update List Item action]

Here's the Workflow Suspended error that I get when I checked the workflow status:
[image: Workflow Suspended Error]

Answer (score 3):

**Is it possible to update information from one choice field into another choice field in a different list?**

Yes, it's possible and I applied this scenario multiple times on my side.

**But** you should be aware of the `value of first choice field` should be **within** `the list of values of the second choice field` in the other list.

**For Example**

The Choice field values in the second List are

- M.Qassas1
- M.Qassas2

And you are tried from the first list workflow to update the Choice field in another list with another value **not** in (M.Qassas1,M.Qassas2) so the workflow will fail.

---

By the way, based on your updated image below,

[image]

The workflow will also fail because the **ID** can't be Status value (string), it should be a number.

Comment: The value field that I listed in the Find the List Item at the bottom, should be "Item Status" as in the other list. I simply assigned the wrong field when I was making the screen shot example. Both "Item Status" fields are choice fields with options of "Closed" "Open". If I change the updated list value to "Current Item: Item Status", what would the "Field" value need to be to make this work?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why this is so puzzling to me, but for the Find the List Item at the bottom, why wouldn't both entries be "Item Status". The way I see it is you are choosing the field in the "User Assigned Invoices" list and assigning it the value of the "Item Status" from the current item in the original list, why wouldn't that work??